# Avoid confusing 2 different ID types

Tags: typescript, eslint

My customers have 2 IDs : `userId` and `customerId`, that are both strings (UUIDs) and refer to 2 different objects in the database.

For now, I can easily send a `customerId` to a function that expects a `userId` as they are both `string` and I am not satisfied with this situation as it is error prone.

I had the idea to create some type aliases like this :

```js
export type CustomerId = string;
export type UserId = string;
```

so my Customer class would look like :

```js
export class Customer {
  id: CustomerId;
  userId: UserId;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can still send a `CustomerId` to a function that expect a `UserId` as both types are considered compatible :

```js
  foo() {
    const userId: UserId = "abc123";
    // This line will compile but I want the compiler to throw an error
    this.bar(userId)
  }

  bar(customerId: CustomerId) {}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TS uses [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/structural-typing).

If you want to distinguish those types you'll have to rely on [branded types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQOwewWwJZQIYBtQBcCeAHApqAM5aEZ5yhx7JSGYAWyGo1AxvZrgQnQK5QIAjrzwAoEKBoATFgDc8UUAgBmnfHUbyGBQsiqgpTZKCwxeoVjVjNkhQggDmUcWGSsATjDtq8hAHSiLqAAKlwAyh4IOBgA5HTY%20EQkZBQ8RBjuvKwYvO5oADSgAO70COyU1LRBKto%20SnSEjPgyqAgA1gTGUllthQixdF09fqAAkqrIQQ4wXgSMg6joGPQ6ep0YGQgARrxkg4MGPYXLCko2qIQw1QfdrG0jAJpmFjSgqNTuinAw7nN4vwAuFgADz0OHeANImWyuTQAFoEkgHIEJMFSnRLIpNAQpHkils3G1CIVlD8QWD3tpfpJqZZCL4giV-p10u4kaAyVBeHAtv8XljkFpCPhWAg0BYYFAyMCbFAZKZeEEpJKYswijRmBgYHI%20XBkB1arI0CJ4nlaMp-nktu8RgAxH5BPCguDgvAAlxBOGgUAAVXp7jGUBwu1AYU2UAcdAAFPxdBaAJSe73BM2EVBMBCS0PhyNJ33%20sZSBQYFRlDNZgBy3N57kIefArFYvjowRgHSqQQA6gRMaAHHhmN9SBzVCdQEbUCJQMpPBRjLBECgllwgsRSORiv0OMZWhtKVt%20iOQRljKwYEWAl28DFqdN2VrQLx6ZJFEgyLW8NlM0ufIUilvJEfARhDECQz1oE83yURQx1JdwKBgCZQBwTx8HcbAXkWPAZAAfRwrYzRkKNlh4a4JSgeQpW-eNilKco9Q6OhDwQF0vHsa0CAfWx7CcSQglgeDxShe9tWMAA1NAEEMMgpFGINdjDNkI0vBICAk1ppOwuTgwwRT2QAXlZdkADJQAAb1APCCOkIEACI-T5bSQwABS8Zh1Kk8soFs0AAF8AG4UTAbtN0WR9n2MZR%20C-LMHxPc0fjnIyI0wK4JHEyTNNk%20TdJzUAvR2TUVmQmAoKKH5lmgGASwjMjliYYpr2pAArJ9mBwshFiRHCQnCSJogYBr%20jiTBMjwS9wOHCdPLIBz3Cc5hDKjJAdKBYSIxo-SAD5zNEb1JuYewXXeDysoW0BDJW3Y-F%20cE3DwKNgAAHQAHmABxClswATIls%20NAu9X4ck%20IgWNdU6mC0nLJDocGZIWvSI0CgKgtACsYCKRr%20QsX4IenaKS0lOgSjKDh-zCyVUCwSRGzwaIgjMAMoDwDGFyQcVVMKaQqqKgh%20yZvJ0HWhwfAmwnmBQt8KzWC7QCjFAqCBWHIZ0hGHE2nazL28jLhtVAYAcOW1j%200RkaCe0AydCk8EKFZfhGy59FjZALWgnTp1nQCn3%20Qo71qiRlk8XgHA4MdpukskuZORReXZNA9aKbDUtAXlkKUmT3VEA7XZDQzbLQf4MCjGIthgLYtipjBkA4wgYnjWzAqzsOIeyt3DKb2b-QW5acuNiWpSlqgo3b5XdmNoIAHkYOK6rbdARg5UKHBuPvYr%20DhYeZCF1Kgj7jAB4IMn0DyHgWTPF0EHeC33E8dwM93-fu50seJCecxexxmRT3gFC8BWWgEC0DAeQ7hZAIGZkeE4SoVAWl%20FKYoyASBJw8NQMgVVFzsy4MSF8MgTgIHcEEE8RY4SIWUExKeaQAAsAAGKhEo4BUDgXrFKABxfoAAJXgWx6iEBEO6EAQR6AbBwIQAEIAHBbk4X4M%20wAACyZRPCXGUBgYAoR8ARDZNEYAPAeG%20GAAAJioXoj06U5QMDSDgNy9RAIOBxodbkep3BYD4cAARQiREgEQOwNAAAvfOdwEBSPgMAVmS4ES4CRHCJAYT1D9WUaIIAA).

```
export type CustomerId = string & {__brand : 'customerId' };
export type UserId = string & {__brand : 'userId' };
```

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I need. If I understand correctly, the right syntax would be `export type UserId = string & {__brand: 'UserId' };` (with a `:` instead of `=`) ?
Now, my compiler is unhappy when I use the wrong ID type, which is good :)

Comment: Yes of course `:`, I've edited !

Comment: Adding a `& never` to the brand type can be a good idea to prevent any attempted usage of the non-existent `__brand` property.